# how to have column output zero when it equals null?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query where i get the average of some ratings
which works correct.

```
WITH row_avg_table(avg_rating,employee, approveddate) AS
(SELECT
(SELECT AVG(rating)
FROM (
VALUES (CAST(c.rating1 AS float)), (CAST(c.rating2 AS float)), (CAST(c.rating3 AS float)), 
(CAST(c.rating4 AS float)), (CAST(c.rating5 AS float)) ) AS v (rating)
WHERE v.rating > 0) avg_rating,
employee,approveddate
FROM CSEReduxResponses c)
SELECT employee,
avg(avg_rating) as average_rating
FROM row_avg_table
where month(approveddate)=2014
AND year(approveddate)=6
GROUP BY employee;
```

The problem im having is when a rating 1-5 would all be 0.
Right now it gives me 'null' i would like it to show 0 for this special occasion.
for example i have the data below

```
create table CSEReduxResponses (rating1 int, rating2 int, rating3 int, rating4 int, rating5 int,
                                approveddate datetime,employee int)

insert into CSEReduxResponses (rating1 , rating2  ,rating3 , rating4 , rating5 ,
                                approveddate, employee )
values 
(5,4,5,1,4,'2014-06-18',1),
(5,4,5,1,0,'2014-06-18',1),
(0,0,0,0,0,'2014-06-19',3);
```

So for employee=3 average_rating =0

Comment: ... do you have `null` or `0`?  They aren't the same thing.  `AVG(...)` will ignore `null`, but not `0` (for obvious reasons).  Taking the average of the average nets a different result than the overall average, so do you want the average daily average, average for the month, or something else?  What should your result rows look like?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `ISNULL` function like below

```
SELECT ISNULL(AVG(rating),some_default_value)
```

(OR) `CASE` condition like below

```
SELECT AVG(case when rating = 0 then 1 else rating end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
isnull(Rating1, 0)
```

or

```
coalesce(Rating1, 0)
```

If `Rating1` is `null` then it will be replaced with the default value `0`. Similartly you can check for other fields. The `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` T-SQL functions are used to return the first nonnull expression among the input arguments but there are few differences between those which you can find [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull)

More details on [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is the `WHERE v.rating > 0` clause. If the ratings are `0`, then this will return no values - and the average of nothing cannot be calculated, and thus returns `null`. Simply remove this clause, or if you want to filter negative values, change it to `WHERE v.rating >= 0`.

If you use `0` to store values that you don't want to impact the rating (like it appears that you might be doing from the second of the examples you provide) this won't work - you'll have to instead go through the output and replace null values with 0. You might copy the results from your first query into a temp table/table variable and do replace such as

```
select employee, rating = isnull(t.rating, 0)
from #temptable t
```

Or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in using a CTE for this. You are unpivoting the non-normalized table using cross apply and values. To arrive at the equivalent of the unpivot command you use WHERE ... IS NOT NULL but presumably you are ensuring all 5 values are present to avoid bias in the calculations, so I would suggest this:

```
SELECT
      employee
    , AVG(isnull(rating,0)) AS avg_rating
FROM CSEReduxResponses c
      CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (CAST(c.rating1 AS float))
            , (CAST(c.rating2 AS float))
            , (CAST(c.rating3 AS float))
            , (CAST(c.rating4 AS float))
            , (CAST(c.rating5 AS float))
            ) AS ca1 (rating)
WHERE approveddate >= '20140601'
      AND approveddate < '20140701'
GROUP BY
      employee
;
```

results from your sample data:

```
| EMPLOYEE | AVG_RATING |
|----------|------------|
|        1 |        3.4 |
|        3 |          0 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f91d9/2

Also: I would encourage you to NOT to use functions on the data to facilitate a where condition. Avoiding functions on data allows use of indexes. Here all you need is a simple date range (I have used YYYYMMDD as it is the safest format for sql server).

Comment: I think this is probably closer to what the OP needs, but you need to move the `ISNULL` to the _outside_ of the `AVG` - if you add `0` several times you're going to lower the result, whereas the `AVG` aggregate will ignore `null` values (You may also have to `NULLIF(...)` the zeros to _get_ null rows...).  Note that it's preferable to use db-agnostic functions like `COALESCE(...)` (instead of `IFNULL(...)`) when possible.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. If the sample size is 5 (the 5 columns unpivoted to 5 rows) and that sample size is important to the result then isnull inside AVG() is vital. In fact originally I used the equivalent of unpivot by excluding null values using a where clause in the cross apply (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f91d9/1 ) only to realize this potential for bias. So I don't think we can be certain of where to place the isnull without more input from user3591637

Comment: the debate over coalesce -v- isnull is just that, a debate. IFnull applies to MySQL and isn't relevant here. Certainly agree it is useful for those folks who deal with multiple dbms's to use coalesce(). But it isn't a matter of right or wrong.